# How to use same generic type in StatefulWidget and State widget?

Tags: flutter, dart

Below is a code mock-up for  generic StatefulWidget that uses a FutureBuilder. I get the following error when FutureBuilder instantiates:

```
type '(User) => Future<List<User>>' is not a subtype of type '(dynamic) => Future<List<dynamic>>'
```

I suspect the error is the compiler wouldn't know that `T` and `U` are the same, so `U` is declared as dynamic while `T` as `User`? How would I change this code so the type used for the generic in the StatefulWidget is passed to State widget?

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) => TestWidget<User>();


class TestWidget<T> extends StatefulWidget {
  final Future<List<T>> Function(T) myFunc = (_) => Future<List<T>>(null);

  @override
  _TestState<T> createState() => _TestState<T>();
}

class _TestState<U> extends State<TestWidget> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return FutureBuilder<List<U>>(
        future: widget.myFunc(null),
        builder: (context, snapshot) {
          return Container();
        });
  }
}
```

Comment: You can easily test that U is the same as T. In fact, you dont even need to change return type of create state: `State createState() => _TestState<T>();`

Comment: The problem is your declaration of myFunc. You probably would need to create a named future to do any sort of work.

Comment: I'm completely in the dark about how this even compiled, given that you pass null as Future's computation

Comment: `Future<List<T>> myFunc(_) async { return []; }` would be a working declaration

Comment: Thanks @AlexeySubbotin. Yeah, the future is useless, but did compile and run. I was more trying to show my struggle with the generics. My actual future runs fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can see how [FutureBuilder](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/blob/3595343e20/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/async.dart#L686) solved this issue. Instead of writing a return type of `_TestState<T>` for the `createState()` method, you would write `State<TestWidget<T>>`.

```
 State<TestWidget<T>> createState() => _TestState<T>();
```

Answer (score 0):

I ended up effectively creating a second `build()` function in the StatefulWidget class that uses the `T` generic. It gets called from the `build()` in the State class. That way the State class doesn't care about the generics. I would have switched to a StatelessWidget with managed states, but I need to use AutomaticKeepAliveClientMixin, so had to stick with a StatefulWidget. My actual State class uses the mixin and has a bit more going on.

```
class TestWidget<T> extends StatefulWidget {
  final Future<List<T>> Function(T) myFunc = (_) => Future<List<T>>(null);

  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return FutureBuilder<List<T>>(
        future: myFunc(null),
        builder: (context, snapshot) {
          return Container();
        });
  }

  @override
  _TestState createState() => _TestState();
}

class _TestState extends State<TestWidget> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return widget.build(context);
  }
}
```